# Why does my program prints out symbols in text file?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that generates random numbers and then stores the generated numbers in a text file. When the code is executed it prints the random numbers, but the text file that was created by the program contains symbols instead of the actual numbers.

Symbols:
C   L   È      z  4   Õ
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char ptr[1000] = "numbers.txt";
int i;
int num = rand();

srand(time(NULL));

fp = fopen(ptr,"w");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Unable to create file.");
    exit(0) ;
}

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    num = rand() % 500 + 1;
    fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("%d\n", num);
}

printf("\n");

fclose(fp) ;
printf("File is created!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the result you want, change

```
fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

to

```
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", num);
```

What you're doing is to write binary data to the file. This writes text instead. Essentially, `printf(args...)` is just a wrapper for `fprintf(stdout, args...)`